# Uber API - get receipt for all trips

Tags: uber-api

ANY IDEA, When can I get receipt of my users trips that did not originate from the request app ? Can the travel history be pulled between two dates ?

As per doc,
The receipt endpoint will only provide receipts for ride requests originating from your application. It is not currently possibly to receive receipt data for all trips.

Comment: The docs are pretty clear and I would assume they have strong commercial and user privacy reasons for not letting you access this.

Comment: The user is only allowing using oauth, so it is users data and Lyft allows it.

Comment: Also For now uber is providing the location, time, and distance travelled. They are not showing the cost of the trip alone. I think is is not privacy here.

Answer (score 2):

The receipt endpoint will only provide receipts for ride requests originating from your application. It is not currently possibly to receive receipt data for all trips.

Comment: It is a genuine use case for enterprise application and integration. Also users is allowing and approve it using oauth.

Comment: If receipt is not possible, can the cost of trip be given as part of history ? https://developer.uber.com/docs/trip-experiences/references/api/v1.2/history-get

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible at this time.

Comment: Is there any place to add it to feature request ?

Comment: I have noted it internally and will update this thread if we make any changes.

Comment: thanks, it will be a useful feature for Enterprise apps and integration